# MobileConnect Outbound SMS API not respecting STOP

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobileconnect

I've submitted a STOP response to a shared short code using my mobile  number. I then attempted to send an Outbound SMS via MobileConnect (to my number and to a colleague).  My colleague received the message, but I did not.

So far so good.

However, when I use the REST API to submit an Outbound SMS, I do receive the SMS message, even though I am presumably still STOPPed. My colleague then also responds with STOP. I send an API Outbound SMS to her number, and she receives the message, too.

Is this a bug or a feature?  If it's a feature, what's the use case for why an Outbound API call would ignore the STOP status of a number?

Here's the payload I'm using:

```
{
    "Subscribers": [
    {
    "MobileNumber": "#here",
    "SubscriberKey": "#here"
    }
    ],
    "Subscribe": "false",
    "Resubscribe": "false",
    "Override": "true",
    "MessageText" : "Outbound Test 3 from the API"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the [postMessageContactSend](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/sms/postMessageContactSend.html) method?

Assuming you are, there could be a couple of reasons this occurs.

Firstly, in the `Subscribers` array, include the same `SubscriberKey` name/value pair that exists for the Subscriber in Marketing Cloud, so it can be 'matched' to the existing Subscriber record. For example:

```
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/messageContact/MzA6Nzg6MA/send
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "Subscribers": [
    {
    "MobileNumber": "15555554410",
    "SubscriberKey": "insertSubscriberKeyHere"
    }
    ],
    "Subscribe": "true",
    "Resubscribe": "false",
    "keyword": "JOINSMS",
    "Override": "false",
    "BlackoutWindow": {
    "UtcOffset": "-0500",
    "WindowStart": "1500",
    "WindowEnd": "2200"
    },
    "SendTime": "2012-10-05 20:01"
}
```

Secondly, in the above example, note that the `Resubscribe` value is set to `false`. If `true`, then the subscription will be reset if the Subscriber is currently unsubscribed.

Comment: You are correct, I am utilizing the postMessageContactSend method. Will edit my question with the payload I'm using. I've been able to continue to bypass the Stop, even when subscribe / resubscribe are False.

Comment: So I've run the exact same tests as last week, but now the results are what I would expect...the STOP is being considered.  So either something was updated with the app, or my tests just weren't legit (although, I did test with a variety of numbers).